# Python: Permission issue when installing an egg

Tags: python, setuptools, egg, distribute

Tried installing [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) sitewide with [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). However I'm having permission issues:

```
drwxr-x---   2 root root   4096 Nov  8 10:23 South-0.7.2-py2.6.egg-info
```

I then tried installing it with [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) but received the same results.

I am assuming I could fix this by just changing the permissions. However, am I doing something wrong during installation? Or is there something wrong with the package?

### Answers to comments

> **iddqd**: Please send output. sudo pip install -e hg+http : //bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/

Here is the results:

```
$ sudo pip-python install -e hg+http://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/
--editable=hg+http://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/ is not the right format; it must have #egg=Package
```

Comment: Paste output of this command: $who am i

Comment: I first ran it using *sudo* but then tried it again by logging in to root thinking it might of been an environment issue. Same results.

Comment: Please send output. sudo pip install -e hg+http : //bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/ remove spaces between http : and //

Comment: @iddqd: Answered in edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be your user and/or root have a specific `umask` which creates files with those permissions such as `0027`.

```
% umask
027
% sudo touch /tmp/foo
% ls -l /tmp/foo
-rw-r-----  1 root  wheel  0 Nov  8 08:19 /tmp/foo
% umask 002
% touch /tmp/bar
% ls -al /tmp/bar
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Nov  8 08:23 /tmp/bar
```

Comment: You are correct---umask=027. Thanks. So is there another option for having python libraries installed correctly sitewide other than changing root's umask from 027 to 002?

Comment: If you install with sudo you inherit whatever umask your user has, not what root's umask is.

Comment: Thank you. What a headache this was. Putting "umask 002" in /etc/profile or in your *shrc will persist the change.